# Is the Material Blazorise supports .figure-is-16x16 class

Tags: c#, html, css, blazorise

Blazorise supports .figure-is-16x16 class but when I'm using in Material then Its not working by-default so I want to that In the Material blazorise it supports or not or if any other class exist related to this then please tell me ? I Add manually this class. but i want this class By default not manually.

```
.figure-is-16x16 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.figure-is-32x32 {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

.figure-is-48x48 {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** A bug fix got merged and will be released in the new version of Blazorise.

It looks like you discovered a bug in Blazorise. The bug is visible in their material demo page: https://materialdemo.blazorise.com/tests/figures.

On the other hand, in their bootstrap demo page size works as expected: https://bootstrapdemo.blazorise.com/tests/figures

I opened an issue on the Blazorise GitHub repository: https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/issues/5015